# Pulseaudio doesn't recognize sink/source if nothing is plugged into the audio ports

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I'm running into an issue where pulseaudio recognizes the presence of my sound card but doesn't recognize the sink or source associated with it (using 'pactl list sinks' shows nothing, but 'pactl list cards' shows correct card information). If I plug in, say, headphones, pactl won't show the sink unless I restart pulse. Seems kind of silly to have to do that.

Anyone run into this issue? Is there a module that I can load to prevent this? I'm only seeing this on my Intel NUC, if that changes anything.

EDIT: After looking at the output of 'pactl list cards' more closely, it seems as though the sound profiles for the card are unavailable. Looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to use `pactl set-card-profile` to set a default profile for each sound card. Once those were set everything worked.

Comment: Worked for me on Xubuntu 20.04, **but** I had to add the `set-card-profile 2 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo` (this is for card #2) to my ~/.config/pulse/default.pa and restart Pulse. My mobo's embedded ALC892 wasn't showing up on the sinks list unless I enabled the device manually on the devices tab of the PAVU GUI while _also_ having something plugged into it. It would forget this device every time Pulse restarted, but now it shows all the time. Did the same for my video card's HDMI audio, which was also never showing automatically, i.e. `set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo`.